# How to convert this sql query to cakephp 3 Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

```
SELECT IF(approved = 1,'Yes','No') AS Status
FROM support;
```

Comment: Why down votes? if you know the answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$supportTable = TableRegistry::get('Support');
$support = $supportTable->find()->select(["status" => "IF(approved = 1,'Yes','No')"])->toArray();
```

You can try this one